# how to read time of whatsapp message from notification in android java?

Tags: java, android

I want to read time of incoming whatsapp message from notification and want to detect delete message so that delete message shown.. If anyone know how to do this please let me know..

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/StatusBarNotification#getPostTime()